# How to implement interface properties NOT in alphabetical order

Tags: c#, visual-studio, interface, shortcut

I use VS 2015.
When I create a new class and try to implement an interface with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> -- For example, `class StarShip : IStarShip`
and then I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> and select `implement interface` -- It implements the properties and methods but in an alphabetical order!
Is there an easy way to make it implement them in the order in which they are in the interface, or must I do it manually?

I don't have Resharper, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VS 'implement interface' functionality obviously uses reflection to generate the code, and there is nothing in the reflection APIs that guarantees the order of members returned by the various calls.  We do not have control over either the reflection order or the VS code generator used to implement interfaces, so we can't change the way it works.

Basically the only option is to use a VS extension like resharper that replaces the implement interface functionality.

Comment: But why is the behavior different in VS2013?

Comment: If you enumerate the members of an interface (`typeof(IList).GetMembers()` for instance) the results are pretty well unordered.  I imagine someone thought that it would improve things to have alphabetical ordering instead of the random-looking ordering that you got before.  That or they had issues with the code that was doing the ordering previously and dropped it in favor of alphabetical.  I don't have a line to the devs so I can't say for sure.

Comment: When you use VS2013 to implement the interface (generate code), it will put the methods in the same order as they are defined in the interface. OP question seems to be why the same does not happen in VS2015, and how, if possible, it can be as in VS2013 for example.

Answer (score 31):

In VS2019 you can change this in the options.

1. `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Implement interface or Abstract class` set to `at the end`.
2. Restart Visual Studio.

This seems to add the functions in the same order as in the interface.

Comment: Yey ! working as charm, don't even need to restart visual studio ;)

Comment: Works in VS2017 as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Not works, methods implemented in random order.